# HSA Contributions without relation to employment

Tags: united-states, hsa

Can I make contributions to my HSA account that I have from an old employer?

I still use the account to buy/pay medical stuff.
I would like to have a little more money in there when I'm investing with it (stocks,etc).

I see it shows up as an account that I can transfer money into, and I want to try but I am not sure of any other implications or surprises that will come next April 15. Are there any implications or penalties (if the system even allows it to go through)?

Comment: Do you currently have health insurance and is it a high-deductible health plan (HDHP)?

Comment: @Nosjack Yes i believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you generally can contribute to an HSA that you had set up while you were with a former employer.  However, you are only able to contribute to any HSA if you are an HSA-eligible individual.  According to [IRS Publication 969](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969#en_US_2019_publink1000204025):

> **Qualifying for an HSA**
>
> To be an eligible individual and qualify for an HSA, you must meet the following requirements.
>
> - You are covered under a high deductible health plan (HDHP), described later, on the first day of the month.
> - You have no other health coverage except what is permitted under [*Other health coverage*](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969#en_US_2019_publink1000204039), later.
> - You aren’t enrolled in Medicare.
> - You can’t be claimed as a dependent on someone else’s 2019 tax return.

If you meet these requirements, you can contribute to an HSA.  If you aren't sure whether or not your health plan qualifies as an HSA-eligible HDHP, ask the health insurance company.  There are stiff penalties for contributing to an HSA when you are not eligible, and there are annual limits to the HSA contributions.

Comment: Well I was getting ready to ask you a slew of clarifications and for some other official documentation, but the link you provided has the direct answer right on it... THANKS!! every article literally contradicted the last.\
from the link: "Contributions to an HSA

Any eligible individual can contribute to an HSA. For an employee’s HSA, the employee, the employee’s employer, or both may contribute to the employee’s HSA in the same year. **For an HSA established by a self-employed (or unemployed) individual, the individual can contribute**.

Comment: Note that pub (like many) is revised each year; for tax year 2019 you couldn't be a dependent in 2019, but for 2020 you can't be a dependent in 2020, and so on. Also the limit amounts can change each year, but the 2019 pub does show the limits for 2020 as well as 2019. And as self-employed I have needed to shop/buy on the PPACA 'exchange' where (at least in my state) many of the plans explicitly market themselves as 'HDHP' and/or 'HSA-eligible'.